Is there a word or phrase for an 'unwanted favor'?
When I give advice to someone and s/he does not need it, is there a word to describe the advice? More generally, is there a word that refers to an act that is meant as a favor but is not received as such?
For example, I give advice, and the listener says something implying that s/he does not need advice from me, then, is there a word such that I can say "Sorry about my ...."?
From what I searched on the web, giving such advice can be called meddling or overstepping (I'm not sure overstepping what), but these do not seem to contain the sense of favor.
===
(EDIT)
From comments and answers, in case of "advice", probably unsolicited advice serves well. But, as a comment suggest, what I'm looking for is the act of doing a favor (including giving advice), or what do-gooder does. So, my question can be phrased as is there a word X such that when someone does X, that means s/he is a do-gooder?.
Seemingly there isn't, but I edited to clarify.

You could call such a person a do-gooder: someone who does things that they think will help other people, although the other people might not find their actions helpful [Cambridge Dictionary]

Unsolicited advice gets across that it wasn't asked for, though not specifically that it was unwelcome.

You might say "Sorry for meddling" or "Sorry for sticking my nose in" after you've given unwanted advice.

Broadly no, and less in the context of that exposition.
I suggest what you seek is not a word to describe the advice, but rather to describe the act of giving the advice.
Does that difference make sense?

The indicated duplicate gives answers that describes the person giving the unsolicited advice, not the action of giving this advice. I have voted to reopen.

I think unsolicited advice recommended by @Kate is the best and more accurate suggestion.
But as a single word, you could use excessiveness which comes form excessive:

If you describe the amount or level of something as excessive, you disapprove of it because it is more or higher than is necessary or reasonable. (Collins)

If it must be a single word, you could also say

Sorry for exaggerating...

or use phrases such as

Sorry for overdoing it...


"Assumption" might be appropriate.
Cambridge Dictionary - Assumption

Something that you accept as true without question or proof


They make the naive assumption that because it's popular it must be
good.

Sorry about my assumption (that my advice might be helpful).
Similarly, consider perhaps "Presumption".
Cambridge Dictionary - Presumption

A belief that something is true because it is likely, although not
certain.


There is no scientific evidence to support such presumptions.

Sorry about my presumption (that my advice might be helpful).
